# Как в Roslyn компиляторе установить версию .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Возникла проблема, при компиляции динамического кода не могу поставить версию фреймворка.

Зависимости:

```
using Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
```

Вот код компиляции:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ProviderOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" }
};

using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
{
  .. setting compile
  CompilerResults ResultLog = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Params, SourceCode);
}
```

Пробую добавить так:

```
using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(ProviderOptions))
```

Или даже так:

```
using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider((ICompilerSettings)ProviderOptions))
```

Но получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> System.InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта
>   "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"
>   к типу
>   "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.ICompilerSettings".

В отличие от CodeDom в котором можно ставить так версию в Roslyn почему-то не получается, как решить ?

Comment: в первом случае какая ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy, В 1-ом случае пишет тоже самое, только в коде, во 2-ом случае при компиляции.

Comment: А чем определяется целевая версия .NET FW? Если версиями системных сборок, то достаточно просто указать нужные версии как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770961/6766879

Comment: Есть еще атрибут `TargetFrameworkAttribute`, но, подозреваю, он имеет чисто информативный характер

Comment: Как вы вообще могли придумать такой способ - брать Dictionary, и кастовать его к ICompilerSettings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За выбор фреймворка отвечает свойство CoreAssemblyFileName класса CompilerParameters. В нем должен быть путь к mscorlib или заменяющей ее библиотеке.

Если оно пусто - берется текущая версия фреймворка.

Вот так, к примеру, можно скомпилировать сборку для фреймворка 2.0:

```
Params.CoreAssemblyFileName = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),
    @"Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll"
);
```

При необходимости, референсные сборки для всех фреймворков можно найти в одной из этих двух папок если у вас стоит MS Build Tools (а они у вас точно стоят, чем-то же вы свой проект собираете):

- `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\`

Comment: Благодарю, а можно ли делать выбор фреймворка допустим через конфиг файл?

Comment: @Дмитрий а что вам мешает?

Comment: @Дмитрий чем настройка "версия фреймворка" отличается от любой другой настройки? Ничем. А значит, вы можете использовать все те способы, которыми добавляются обычные настройки.

Comment: Ваш способ работает, компилирует файл под `Net2.0` но файлы становятся не рабочими ( крашится просто ). Полагаю из-за того что там так же присутствуют другие ссылки (но уже из другой версии ). Как добавить много ссылок? [Создал отдельно тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/885927/Дубликаты-ссылок-mscorlib-в-roslyn-при-компиляции)