# Дубликаты ссылок mscorlib в Roslyn при компиляции

Tags: c#, roslyn

Путь к `.dll` файлам брал от сюда:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\`

```
List<string> DLL = new List<string>(); //тут уже лежит список путей к .dll
using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
{
   // DLL.ToArray() добавляю ссылки 
   var Params = new CompilerParameters() 
   {
     //parametrs build
   };
   provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Params, SourceCode) // compile
}
```

Но во время компиляции получаю ошибку:

> error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported: 
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'  and 
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference\Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll'.
>
> Remove one of the duplicate references.

Как исправить?

---

[**Дополнительная информация**]

Сам проект скомпилирован под `.Net4.5`

(специально для **Roslyn**, под другие версии *NetFramework* его библиотеки он не ставит)

Если брать такой код:

```
List<string> DLL = new List<string>() // просто файлы
{
   "mscorlib.dll", "System.Data.dll"
}
using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
{
  var Params = new CompilerParameters(DLL.ToArray())
  {
     //parametrs build
  };
  provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Params, SourceCode) // compile
}
```

То всё работает, но ссылки из `List<string>` он добавляет от как бы самого проекта ( под котором он скомпилирован ) P.S: Не из папок!

А мне нужно добавить из нужной мне папки, но если я этого делаю (см 1-ый пост )
то получаю ошибку о том что нельзя добавить библиотеки `.dll` из разных папок.
Как мне получить нужные мне библиотеки и добавить их в сборку я не знаю как.

---

[**Что предпринимал?** ]

Попробовал удалить из того файла который компилируется ссылки (`usings`).

Попробовал удалить файл `packages.config`

Но всё безрезультатно.

Comment: Очевидно, брать файлы не из всех подпапок, а только из одной — с нужной версией фреймворка. Просто откройте эту папку в проводнике и посмотрите что в ней

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Я собираю только из нужной версии фреймворка, прохожусь по папкам ( в нужной версии) ищу нужные мне файлы и добавляю в `List<string> DLL`. Если собираю файлы из `v4.0` фреймворка то всё работает нормально. (Сам проект скомпилирован в `Net v4.5`).

Comment: Ага, вижу у вас `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll` еще подхватилась

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Roslyn как-то автоматом генерирует эти файлы под `4.0` я не знаю как от этого избавиться. мне по сути нужно как-то сделать так чтобы он собирал ссылки только из нужной только папки ( на примере из `v3.5` ) а из самой сборки проекта ( под которой он скомпилирован )

Comment: Выглядит так как будто свойство CoreAssemblyFileName пустое...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Обновил.

Comment: @Дмитрий а список DLL вы откуда берете?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Прочитайте 2-ую строчку)) из той папки я беру файлы .dll  и добавляю их в лист стринг DLL. После уже работаю с этим листом с уже известными мне путями где хранится нужные .dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>По умолчанию компилятор добавляет ссылки на системные сборки, прописанные в файле csc.rsp в его каталоге. Добавьте параметр компилятора [nostdlib](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/nostdlib-compiler-option) или [noconfig](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/noconfig-compiler-option), если вам это не нужно</s>

На самом деле, это не работает. Поведение Roslyn отличается от традиционного С#-компилятора в том, что добавление опции `/nostdlib` не имеет никакого эффекта, все равно будет добавлена ссылка на mscorlib 4.0. Единственный способ не добавлять ссылку на нее, это установить свойство [CoreAssemblyFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.coreassemblyfilename?view=netframework-4.7) на путь к другой версии mscorlib и не добавлять ссылку ни одну сборку, зависимую от "ненужной" версии.

Comment: Ключ `/nostdlib` добавляется автоматически. Вот `/noconfig` интереснее...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я не заметил, что автор добавил установку свойства CoreAssemblyFileName. Без него действительно был нужен nostdlib. А в текущий редакции у него код походу вообще рабочий (по крайней мере, на hello world ошибок не выдает).

Comment: Без него `/nostdlib` тоже не помогает. Просто потому что mscorlib автоматически добавляется в список зависимостей.

Comment: @Дмитрий грр! Указать CoreAssemblyFileName, конечно же...  Хватит задавать мне один и тот же вопрос. Если я узнаю на него другой ответ - я скажу об этом и без вашего напоминания.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, действительно, в Roslyn /nostdlib, по видимому, не имеет никакого эффекта, все равно добавляется ссылка на mscorlib 4.0 (в традиционном C#-компиляторе это работает по другому, если добавить /nostdlib, но не указать вручную ссылку на другую mscorlib, компиляция завершится с ошибкой )

Comment: @Дмитрий Да, вам нужно добавить ссылки на все нужные сборки из той же (или более старой) версии .NET. Вы легко узнаете, что нужная сборка не добавлена, так как компилятор выведет ошибку вроде "Не найден тип"

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, А не подскажите почему крашится любое приложение скомпилированное под `.Net 2.0` ? Даже обычный Hello world

Comment: @Дмитрий Не знаю. Задайте новый вопрос, с кодом и информацией об исключении, тогда попробуем разобраться.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, А что Вы можете сказать на счёт [/lib + /reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/lib-compiler-option). Ведь можно явно передать путь с .dll внутрь этого `/lib:путь к .dll файлам` ?

Comment: И мне почему-то кажется что есть возможность использовать его в связке с `/nostdlib` могу ошибаться, но думаю что всё верно. нужно пробовать)