# Не компилируется динамическая программа на .NET Framework 4.5.2

Tags: c#, winforms

Я раньше писал программу на .net 4.5, но решил перейти на 4.5.2. В связи с этим потребовалось и здесь сменить версию:

```
Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {
        "CompilerVersion",
            "v4.5.2"
    }
};
CSharpCodeProvider csharpCodeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
```

Теперь я получаю исключение, что файл компилятора csc.exe не найден. Я уже сталкивался с такой ошибкой, но тогда просто забыл поменять версию в компилирующей программе, а сейчас абсолютно уверен, что она изменена. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Вы точно не путаете версии компилятора/языка и .NET? Они взаимосвязаны, но не  равнозначны, поэтому уточните, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Судя по коду [RedistVersionInfo](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/codedom/compiler/RedistVersionInfo.cs,2558aaadfbb8306b), в котором у вас скорее всего падает - CompilerVersion - это просто имя ветки в реестре, и оно должно быть v4.0 (ну или вообще пустым). По крайней мере у меня, с кучей поставленных версий 4.5/4.6/4.7 в реестре в "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSBuild\\ToolsVersions\\" есть только "4.0"

Comment: Этот самый код работает, когда я ввожу 4.5 в значение версии .NET. Но вызывает исключение, если ввожу 4.5.2.

Comment: Вам уже сказали: Вы путаете версию компилятора и .NET Framework

Comment: Тогда какую версию компилятора нужно использовать, чтобы программа была собрана с .net 4.5.2?

Comment: Целевая платформа указывается вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/883821/240512 Версию компилятора, скорее всего, нужно оставить 4.5. Компилятор 4.5 умеет собирать под 4.5.2.

Comment: Да, только в папке .net 4.0, а как правильно указать целевую платформу 4.5.2?

Comment: В какой папке? В `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework` должны быть все версии, которые доступны как целевые платформы в Visual Studio.

Comment: Да, там действительно все версии. Только я все равно не могу определить версию платформы в собранной программе - в dnSpy атрибута нет. Установка атрибута TargetFramework приводит к тому, что программа спустя секунду закроется.

Comment: Я думал атрибут TargetFramework вообще ни на что не влияет, странно. "*программа спустя секунду закроется*" - просто закроется, или упадет с ошибкой? В журнале событий что-нибудь появляется?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался со всем. Дело было в том, что я неверно заполнил атрибут.